# raw bits to pixel transformation / translation

Tags: c++, binary

hello every one. As the question explains itself.

The bitmap pixel is something like this (24-bit RGB) :

---

|**8bit_**|_8bit_***|*_8bit__**|
    R           G         B

Where as any raw data from my .bin file is plane bits(16-bit in my case), hence I am quite confused how can we transform such data into the pixel form.

Kashan

Comment: Not sure what you are doing but I suggest you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth

Comment: thanks, reading...!
in the meantime, I am taking ultrasonic data from using my FPGA based DAQ system and then based on these we are making a movie. Each signal is 16-bit raw data and hence need to transformed in a way to generate movie.